# Keeping getting server and network error when trying to retrieve data from my LoopBack api

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback4

When I open my loopback API in Firefox try and use the GET commands for the controllers on my user and plant collection from my mongodb
I get this response from the Curl

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://[::1]:3000/users?filter=%7B%0A%20%20%22offset%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22limit%22%3A%20100%2C%0A%20%20%22skip%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22order%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%22where%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22additionalProp1%22%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22fields%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22userID%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22email%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22phoneNumber%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22plantsRegistered%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

And this response from the Request URL

```
http://[::1]:3000/users?filter=%7B%0A%20%20%22offset%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22limit%22%3A%20100%2C%0A%20%20%22skip%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22order%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%22where%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22additionalProp1%22%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22fields%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22userID%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22email%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22phoneNumber%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22plantsRegistered%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D
```

And I get this message when I open up the firefox inspector

```
Source map error: Error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: http://[::1]:3000/explorer/swagger-ui.css
Source Map URL: swagger-ui.css.map
```

Within the server response it appears as

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

I also got a server error(

Error: Internal Server Error) with the response body(I tried opening the API on chrome and got this error. I got this error on Firefox as well

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this so I'm hoping I could find a potential solution on here